# It took too long to get a response for this URL, so we will not scrape this content -linkedin

Tags: html, laravel, linkedin-api, meta-tags

I am trying to share an article on linkedin. Everything is okay but linkedin does not recognize featured image.
I put my article URL on Linkedin **Post inspector tool**

Post inspector tool result: **It took too long to get a response for this URL, so we will not scrape this content**

screenshot of linkedin post inspector tool result

[image]

I search on google why linkedin can not pull featured Image. I find a solution described in this article 
https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en

I placed og tag accordingly.

I changed image width to 1200px height to 800px.

I kept image size under 5MB but it does not fix the problem.

**Then I changed file permission to server.**
I changed permission of storage->app->public->posts to 755. Image file permission generates 644 by default. I used laravel framework to my blog website if this information is helpful.

**I also checked facebook debugger tool that works fine**

screenshot of facebook debugger tool result

[image]

This is my open graph API implementation

```
<!-- open graph api start -->
    <meta property="og:title" content="Finding the best website design and development company in Dhaka Bangladesh" />
    <meta property='og:description' content="As you are reading this post, I am assuming you are looking for a website design and development company in Bangladesh or you are enthusiastic in a web design and development career. Whatever is the case, I am going to.... Finding the best website design and development company in Dhaka Bangladesh"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.chotosite.com/finding-the-best-website-design-and-development-company-in-dhaka-bangladesh" />
    <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://www.chotosite.com/storage/posts/1577983797Best-website-design-and-development-company-in-Bangladesh.png" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://www.chotosite.com/storage/posts/1577983797Best-website-design-and-development-company-in-Bangladesh.png" />
    <!-- open graph api end -->
```

And this is my article URL: https://www.chotosite.com/web-design-company

If you need more information please View source code. I am beginner in programming. I think there might be a problem somewhere in the code. Help me please. Thank you...

Comment: Seems to work file according to [this link](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/https:%2F%2Fwww.chotosite.com%2Ffinding-the-best-website-design-and-development-company-in-dhaka-bangladesh).

Comment: Doesn't work to me.

Comment: Good News ! I followed linkedIn guideline and wait for a few days And it fixed.